# Integrate Python's Django into a C++ application

Tags: c++, python, django, integration

I would like to integrate Python, and specifically Django, to a C++ application. This is for many reasons which include, but not limited to:

- Ease of data handling and feature development in python
- Django's amazing ORM
- Django's instant admin interface

etc...

My specific application is a real-time event intensive application. The Python\Django aspects should mainly come in the initial data loading part, batch data dumps and semi-real time web access for tracking and configuration.

How would you go about integrating these very different programing languages and design concepts?

Answer (score 4):

I would strongly recommend considering to integrate the other way around: your C++ application into Python. A good article on the [tradeoffs of extending vs. embedding](http://twistedmatrix.com/users/glyph/rant/extendit.html).

Also, re the Django/web server part, it's not always recommended to have a monolithic application that's too large. Consider breaking the web-serving part into a separate application, purely Django on Python, that will communicate with your main application via either OS files or sockets, or some other IPC. You're still welcome to add Python to your main application (by extending or embedding) for the other needs.

Comment: the "extending vs. embedding" link is great! Also - I don't plan to have the company's entire website running with the dedicated C++ real-time program, but I do want some minimal web interface for interaction. I'll check the sockets approach though.

Comment: @Jonathan: presumably you also don't plan to embed your whole company's website into your C++ real-time program :-) That's why separation is the best approach here, IMHO